# How can I send volley request?

Tags: android, android-volley

How can I send volley request when using json array? I'm working on the following code.

It's showing this error

> NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 1 java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 1

```
public class MyService2 extends Service {
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());


private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
private final Context mContext= this;

final class MyThreadClass implements Runnable{


    int service_id;
    MyThreadClass(int service_id){
        this.service_id = service_id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query( ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        final JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray();

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            contactList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                JSONObject contact1 = new JSONObject();
                String ID = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String NAME = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("name : " + NAME + ", ID : " + ID);
                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{ID}, null);

                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put( Variables.TOKEN, new DefaultPreferences(MyService2.this)
                            .getValueString(Variables.TOKEN));
                    try {
                        contact1.put("Name", NAME);
                        contact1.put("ID", ID);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        JSONObject _contact = new JSONObject();

                        String PHONE = pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        System.out.println("phone" + PHONE);
                        try {
                            _contact.put("PHONE", PHONE);
                            jsonArray.put(_contact);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }


                    pCur.close();


                    // get email and type
                    Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{ID}, null);

                    JSONArray jsonEmailArray = new JSONArray();
                    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                        JSONObject _contact = new JSONObject();

                        // This would allow you get several email addresses
                        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                        String EMAIL = emailCur.getString(
                                emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                                emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                        System.out.println("Email " + EMAIL + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                    }
                    emailCur.close();
                    try {
                        contact1.put("PHONES", jsonArray);
                        contact1.put("EMAILS", jsonEmailArray);
                        contacts.put(contact1);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        String url = "http://nojoto.com/appapi/userDetails.php";
        VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest( Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", "NAME");
                params.put("id", "ID");
                params.put("phone", "PHONE");
                params.put("email", "EMAIL");
                return params;
            }


        };


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);

    }
}




public MyService2() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Thread thread = new Thread(new MyThreadClass(startId));
    thread.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}





@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());
    startService(restartServiceIntent);
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}


}
```

Comment: `requestQueue.add(multipartRequest)`... You already have that, so what's the problem?

Comment: Its showing error  NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 1
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 1

Comment: "Bad URL" seems self explanatory